# Cでscanfを使わずにスペース区切りの二つの整数を読み込むコードが想定通りに動かない

Tags: c

Cでscanfを使わずにスペース区切りの二つの整数を読み込むコードを書きたいのですが、二つ目の数が正確に読み込めないです。
(１つ目の数をかけた数になっている模様。)
原因がわかりません。

```
int readint(char *s);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 1000000100
int main(void){
    char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    fgets(s,N,stdin);
    int n=readint(s);
    int i=0;
    while(*(s+i)!=32)i++;
    i++;
    int d=readint(s+i);
    free(s);
    printf("%d %d\n",n,d);
    return 0;
}
int readint(char *s){
    int i=0,ret=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
//        printf("%d\n",*(s+i));
        ret*=10;
        ret+=(ret+*(s+i)-48);
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

22行目が間違っています。

誤：

```
    ret+=(ret+*(s+i)-48);
```

正：

```
    ret+=*(s+i)-48;
```